# ObjectInputStream gives StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, httprequest, objectinputstream

I want to convert the `inputStream (HttpRequest.getInputStream())` to an Object.

```
try {
        ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream (inputStream);
        resObject= ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the `inputStream` contains **xml** in the form of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot directly use `ObjectInputStream` here because, it expects a serialized object, not an XML string.

What you probably could do is unmarshal the inputstream content into the desired object using an unmarshaller / Java XML binding APIs. like `JAXB` and quite a few other APIs out there.

A sample link to get you started on this : [Tutorials point link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/xml/javax_xml_bind_jaxb_unmarshal_inputstream.htm)
And unmarshalling in general : [java.net link](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) which has a little explanation as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the data is not XML but just some character data.How can i convert it into an object

Comment: Then you need a method of processing that data. Depends on what type of data is being sent. For XML : Unmarshal, JSON : Use GSON library.

Whichever way you go, you need to de-serialize the data being received into the java object. Or else, parse the character data manually and retrieve information for populating the Object instance(s).